# How to use a Python data frame to generate a list/sequence that can be added as a column

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, sequence

I have created a data frame from a sql query that generates bin data for a histogram: min, max, and bin size. I want to use this data to create a list of bins that I can then merge back into the original data frame

[Here is a sample of my query output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DKro.jpg)

My query produces one row per model. I want to then create a list that starts at the initial_bin (0) and then increments by bin_size (7) until it reaches the maximum (435). The resulting column will be called bin_seq.

My code below shows where I'm at so far. I can generate a list with the desired sequence using a for loop and the range() function, but am unsure on how to merge this back into the data frame.

'''

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
bin_sql = """
select 'test_model_1' model,  0 initial_bin , 435 maximum , 7 bin_size
    from analytics.model_data
        
"""

bin_data = pd.read_sql(bin_sql,conn)

bin_max = int(bin_data["maximum"]+bin_data["bin_size"])
bin_size = int(bin_data["bin_size"])
bin_start = int(bin_data["initial_bin"])

for i in range(bin_start, bin_max, bin_size):
    print(i, end=', ')
```

'''

[Here is the image of the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlSDz.jpg)

One additional wrinkle on this is that my final output will have multiple models, each with its own maximum and bin size. So I will need to be able to generate a custom sequence for each model and then join the sequence back to the original model name.

Comment: Update your post with a sample of `bin_data` like `bin_data.head()`, please.

Comment: @Corralien -- just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['test_model', 0, 435, 7]],
                  columns=['model', 'initial_bin', 'maximum', 'bin_size'])
print(df)

# Output
        model  initial_bin  maximum  bin_size
0  test_model            0      435         7
```

```
bin_seq = lambda x: range(x['initial_bin'], x['maximum'], x['bin_size'])
df = df.assign(bin_seq=df.apply(bin_seq, axis=1)) \
       .explode('bin_seq').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

# Output
         model  initial_bin  maximum  bin_size bin_seq
0   test_model            0      435         7       0
1   test_model            0      435         7       7
2   test_model            0      435         7      14
3   test_model            0      435         7      21
4   test_model            0      435         7      28
..         ...          ...      ...       ...     ...
58  test_model            0      435         7     406
59  test_model            0      435         7     413
60  test_model            0      435         7     420
61  test_model            0      435         7     427
62  test_model            0      435         7     434

[63 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate the desire output you want. You didn't mentioned how to calculate bin_seq.

> ```
> import pyodbc
> import pandas as pd
> bin_sql = """
> select 'test_model_1' model,  0 initial_bin , 435 maximum , 7 bin_size
>     from analytics.model_data
>         
> """
>
> bin_data = pd.read_sql(bin_sql,conn)
>
> bin_max = int(bin_data["maximum"]+bin_data["bin_size"])
> bin_size = int(bin_data["bin_size"])
> bin_start = int(bin_data["initial_bin"])
> bin_sq=[]
> ## For creating bin Sequence
> temp=0
> ## Generating bin_seq
> for i in range(bin_start, bin_max, bin_size):
>     bin_sq.append(temp)
>     temp=temp+bin_size
> ## Adding bin_seq in dataframe
> bin_data['bin_seq']=bin_sq
> ```